# JDBCConnectionException sometimes with spring data and amazon RDS

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, amazon-rds

Often times I have to restart a microservice that we have because I get a DataAccessResourceFailureException and JDBCConnectionException after a period of time (6-12 hours) (I inserted the stacktrace below). I'm using Spring data and the DB is AWS RDS

Here's a snippet of my config file that I thought would fix the issue

`spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query= SELECT 1
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle= true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-borrow= true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.time-between-eviction-runs-millis= 5000`

```
[E] s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:    Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor80.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 39,231,404 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 39,231,405 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataAccessResourceFailureException -> 
Data access exception thrown when a resource fails completely, eg: if we can't connect to a database using JDBC.My suspicion is we are getting the error due to the Connection.

Please try to look logs of RDS.

And also what I understand from log is MySQLNonTransientConnectionException. So which is due to dropping of connection from pool after the timeout.

So the best option is to configure the timeout, eviction-time to be more. But what your application is doing is correct and it is not recommended to have bigger timeout or eviction-time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297356/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-in-jdbc-program-at-run-time also this question will answer your question precisely.