# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new in Databases just started to learn them. I have MySQL Server 8.0., Workbench 8.0, Java connector 5.1.31, Java 1.8 itself. Followed multiple guides for newbies how to start with.

So there is the case. I have database on localhost and successfully connect to it with workbench and via windows prompt. But after I execute code in java:

```
        Driver sqlDriver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(sqlDriver);
        Connection sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root", "root", "root");
```

I get exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`

Why it could happen? I've tried to reinstall MySQL, Cleaned OS variables, looked everywhere and couldn't find solution. Would be glad to find it here.

UPD:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2328)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3309)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2346)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297356/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-in-jdbc-program-at-run-time

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, it provides more information to determine the underlying cause. In any case, MySQL Connector/J is pretty old, you might want to try a newer version like 5.1.46 or 8.0.11. Also be aware that you likely shouldn't be using the `FabricMySQLDriver`, let alone register it yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you. Tryed connector version 5.1.46 and it works. Updated head message with full stacktrace I had before

Comment: @MarkRotteveel And why I shouldn't use  FabricMySQLDriver? Is it wrong or just redundant?

Comment: The Fabric driver is for Highly Available MySQL deployments, which I don't think you're using. On top of that, it requires a specific JDBC URL (fabric would require `jdbc:mysql:fabric:` as the prefix), so right now you're just using the automatically loaded normal driver.

Answer (score 69):

The problem is the compatibility of older versions of MySQL Connector/J with MySQL 8. You need to upgrade to either MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46 or - better - 8.0.11 (or a higher version).

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I was using Maven Dependency to use JDBC connector. I just changed the version of dependency. This worked for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add the below version and you will be fine:

```
<mysql.driver.version>8.0.20</mysql.driver.version>
```

Comment: This was my case.