# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I can connect to my database from client , but could not connect from application, (mysql server is working).
I can not get connection from datasource with this properties.

Problem:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3276)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1940)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1866)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
```

mysql connector:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

version mysql: 8.0.13

My properties for connection:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sport_club4
db.username=root
db.password=12345
#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.netcracker.devschool.dev4.etalon.entity
```

Comment: try adding `?serverTimezone=UTC` at the end of the connection string

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177907/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-could-not , the driver version you use is not compatible with your mysql version, try use the 5.1.46 or later

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sport_club4?serverTimezone=UTC didnt help

Comment: thanks, update version help