# Cannot create connection to database using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am new to JDBC and using a tutorial to create my first connection. However, I am getting the below error -

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//demo";
    String user="root";
    String password="vishal123";
    String query = "select * from student";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery(query);
    rs.next();
    String name = rs.getString("user_name");
    System.out.println(name);
    st.close();
    con.close();
}

}
```

Do let me know if you need any more details to solve the problem.

Comment: Change double slash in your URL `//demo` to `/demo` Also make sure your mysql server is up and running by logging into it through some other tool like command promt

Comment: i did the above mentioned things, but still getting the same error

Comment: Actually I was using mysql server 8 and mysql jar 5.1.38. I changed my jar to 8.0.13
It worked.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and not just the top message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177907/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-could-not)