# jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connecion to database server

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to connect to my database by using the java code below, but I got the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nofoodleft?useSSL=false","root","123");
        Statement myStmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nofoodleft");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("site"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be a compatibility problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177907/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-could-not

Comment: My Mysql version is 8.0.15.

Comment: What about the driver?

Comment: How to check the driver version?

Comment: Look at the JAR.  Get the right one here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: My connector/J version is 8.0.15 now, but still got that error :(

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace