# JSP GlassFish error

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

I'm trying to create a regsitration app using netbeans java web project.I've created a database called testdb and created a table called users.Unfortunately received a mistake and couldn't new add datas to table.Mistakes listed from Glassfish Output below.Here's what i tried

Index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="process.jsp">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="first_name">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="last_name">
      <br>
      City name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="city_name">
      <br>
      Email Id:<br>
      <input type="email" name="email">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");

try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb","root","123456");
  Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
  int i=stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERS(first_name,last_name,city_name,email)VALUES('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+city_name+"','"+email+"')");
  out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.print(e);
  e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Mistake that i recieved from GlassFish output

```
Info:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Severe:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured(ExportControlled.java:401)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:103)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1663)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.jsp.process_jsp._jspService(process_jsp.java:61)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured(ExportControlled.java:381)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: problem looks like it's happening because you're not closing your database connection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297356/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-in-jdbc-program-at-run-time

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"` after entering the database URL in the `getConnection` method:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","username","password");
```